# Xpath select multiple elements

Tags: xpath

Is there any ways to make the following lines shorter? 
Can i select both /span/strong[2] and /strong[2] in one line without "|"?

```
//*[@id="content"]/div[2]/div[2]//following-sibling::p[1]/span/strong[2] | //*[@id="content"]/div[2]/div[2]//following-sibling::p[1]/strong[2]
```

Comment: Can you try `p[1]//strong[2]` ? It means all strong[2] descendants of p[1]

Comment: If you'd post your actual goal and your targeted HTML, we'd probably find not only a shorter but also a more robust XPath for you.

Comment: Oh, that actually works fine. Thank you.

Comment: Ok good, so I've post it as answer

Comment: Is there is a way to add also [@id="content"]/div[2]/div[2]/p[9]/span/strong and [@id="content"]/div[2]/div[2]/p[10]/span/strong? 
In short, how should i change my xpath to select all strong[2] and just strong elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `p[1]//strong[2]`

It means all `strong[2]` descendants of `p[1]`

Comment: Ok, thank you. But can i also add somehow [@id="content"]/div[2]/div[2]/p[10]/span/strong? and [@id="content"]/div[2]/div[2]/p[9]/span/strong?
I don't need all strong elements, just those in p[10] and p[9]. 
How should i modify p[1]//strong[2] to include p[10]/span/strong and p[9]/span/strong?

Comment: @Michael Can you ask this other question in a new post please? On StackOverflow we try to avoid questions in comments. Otherwise it will be hardly reusable by other users ;) Thanks!

Comment: Ok, i'll ask it. Sorry, just encountered a urgent issue that has to be solved fast, so i didn't really have time to learn xpath properly.

Answer (score 0):

why dont't you just use the second path only

```
//*[@id="content"]/div[2]/div[2]//following-sibling::p[1]/strong[2]
```

it contains both directives.

Comment: The problem is when i use only second path, some of the elements that i need to be selected stay uselected and the only way to select them all - use both paths/